# How to compare each object of one NSMutableArray with other

Tags: ios4

In `arr3` I want the index of the object from `arr1` when `arr1[k]==arr2[m]`.

However, I am not getting the value in `arr3` because it must not satisfy if condition.

How can I compare two NSMutableArray objects by their indices?

```
while (k<=[arr1 count]-1 ) {
    for (m=0; m<=[arr2 count]-1; m++) {

    if ([arr1 objectAtIndex:k]==[arr2 objectAtIndex:m]) {
        [arr3 addObject:k];
    }
    }
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr1,*arr2,*arr3;

arr1=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"vijay",@"india",@"AppleVijay@facebook.com",nil];

arr2=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"vijay",@"AppleVijay@facebook.com",nil];

arr3=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    //Note: Here u have to properly create those arr1,arr2,arr3 arrays with alloc and init and also add objects for arr1,arr2 for compare.


for (id obj in arr2) {//each obj in arr2


    if ([arr1 containsObject:obj]) {//if arr1 has the same obj(which is from arr2)

        [arr3 addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:[arr1 indexOfObject:obj]]];//then add that indexofobject to arr3

    }

}


NSLog(@"resulted arr3 : %@ \n\n",arr3);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
resulted arr3 : (

                 0,

                 2

                 )
```